# Collection.update() with callback returns undefined

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, meteor

In Meteor, I use the return value from Collection.update() (`1`) on the client to display a message to the user. The method runs on both the client and on the server.

Consider the following method, which works as expected (returns `1`):

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateDocument(documentId) {
        return Collection.update(
            documentId, 
            {$set: {updatedBy: this.userId}}
        );
    }
});
```

Next, consider the following method, which returns `undefined`:

```
Meteor.methods({
   updateDocument(documentId) {
        return Collection.update(
            documentId,
            {$set: {updatedBy: this.userId}},
            (error, result) => {
                return 1;
            }
        );
    }
});
```

What am I missing here? Why doesn't `updateDocument()` return `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a callback function, then the `update` call is asynchronous. It returns nothing, and your Meteor method may finish before the update is done.

Quoting from [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update):

> On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then update blocks
>   until the database acknowledges the write, or throws an exception if
>   something went wrong. If you do provide a callback, update returns
>   immediately. Once the update completes, the callback is called with a
>   single error argument in the case of failure, or a second argument
>   indicating the number of affected documents if the update was
>   successful.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I understand. Now, how can I let the user know that the update was successful? In other words, how can the event function on the client know that the document was successfully updated if the method it calls doesn't return anything?

Comment: The synchronous `update` function throws an exception if there's an error. Be a good Pokemon master and catch 'em all. :)